# How to remove solutions from a Prolog program

Tags: prolog

Given this program:

```
a(1). a(2). a(3).
b(1). b(2). b(3).
ab(A, B) :- a(A), b(B).
```

This query returns 9 items:

```
ab(A, B).
```

How do I remove some specific rows, for example the rows (1,2) and (3,1) and get this result?

```
1 1
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 2
3 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode a list of values for `A` and `B` you do not want, like:

```
not_ab(1,2).
not_ab(3,1).
```

Then you can use the [**`\+/1`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%2B)/1) that acts as negation:

```
ab(A, B) :-
    a(A),
    b(B),
    \+ not_ab(A, B).
```

Note that Prolog's negation is *negation as finite failure*. It thus means that `\+ Goal` succeeds, geven all attempts to satisfy `Goal` fail, and that these attempts are finite (as in, the program does not get stuck in an infinite loop, and the number of brenches is finite).

The above is a *generate-and-test* approach: we first *generate* values for `A` and `B` and then *test* if these are valid. If you however can already know if for a given value for `A` all values of `B` will fail, then it is better to interleave testing. Here however it looks as if we can only test if both `A` and `B` are known.